# Rails cache expire

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a rails application, in that I am using simple rails cache. My testing is as follows:

```
Rails.cache.write('temp',Date.today,:expires_in => 60.seconds)
```

I can read it through `Rails.cache.read('temp')` and `Rails.cache.fetch('temp')`.

The problem is it doesn't expire. It will still be alive after 60 seconds. Can any one tell me what is missing here.

**FYI:  I have declared in my development.rb as follows :**

```
config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

config.cache_store = :memory_store
```

Is there anything I missed out? I want to expires my cache.

Answer (score 13):

After some search, I have found one possible reason why the cache is not cleaned after 60 seconds.

1. You call `Rails.cache.write` which is documented [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Cache/Store.html#method-i-write).
2. It calls `write_entry(namespaced_key(name, options), entry, options)`, where your option `:expires_in` is one part of the `options` argument.
3. The [implementation of `write_entry`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/Cache/MemCacheStore/write_entry) has the following condition:

   ```
   if expires_in > 0 && !options[:raw]
       # Set the memcache expire a few minutes in the future to support race condition ttls on read
       expires_in += 5.minutes
   end
   ```

So there are 5 minutes added to your 60 seconds. 2 possible solutions:

- Just live with it :-)
- Try to include the option `:raw => true`, perhaps this will skip the condition, so that your expiry works as suspected.

Comment: Yes mliebelt right,  also a good rails cache doc you can find here http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html

Answer (score 9):

The `:expires_in` option only works with compatible stores (eg memcached) - not memory.

From http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html:

> Finally, if you are using memcached or Ehcache, you can also pass
>   :expires_in. In fact, all parameters not used by caches_action are
>   sent to the underlying cache store.

Comment: FYI, `expires_in` works just fine with `FileStore` on Rails 5.2.

Comment: This does appear to be Rails version specific.  https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v5.2/caching_with_rails.html says nothing of what stores `expires_in` is limited to.  Check the docs!

Comment: Despite documentation changes, `expires_in` won't work with `:memory_store` (which is what the question is asking about).

Answer (score 0):

You should use fetch method with do block instead of Rails.cache.write. Even though the name is "fetch", it writes to the cache if you put inside do block. You also do not need to clear cache entry manually, just use the "fetch" with expires_in and race_condition_ttl. Keep the ttl value under expiry time and keep it as small as possible.

```
output_json = Rails.cache.fetch('temp',expires_in: 1.minute,race_condition_ttl:3) do
  my_expansive_operation().to_json
end
```