# Why does Rails cache expiration doesn't work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, caching

I'm trying to setup cache expiration time like this:

```
Rails.cache.write('trash', items, expires_in: 30.seconds)
```

or like this

```
Rails.cache.read('trash', expires_in: 30.seconds)
```

but nothing works in my case. The cache is not deleted/invalidated after the expiration time passes.

Comment: Looks like this has been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8846400/rails-cache-expire

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rails cache expire](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8846400/rails-cache-expire)

Answer (score 0):

Low-level caching, which you are trying to do here, doesn't work with Memstore ([yellow box](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#basic-caching)), the default for development. You'll have to setup something like MemCached or Redis for development.